# Write a constructor from class that returns 2 values

Tags: java, math

I have a class that separates a double to whole part and the fraction part.  I want to use those separately when I create an object from that class.

I tried this as a function but a function only has 1 return value or I can do it a return array, I know this. I just wonder if I can do it somehow more elegantly

Constructor of the class

```
    public wholeAndFraction(double db){
    String st=""+db;
    st=st.replace(".", "-");
    String[] str=st.split("-");
    int whole=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int fraction=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);}
```

When I generate an object I want to invite whole or the fraction part like

```
    wholeAndFraction first=new wholeAndFraction(5.32);
    System.out.println(first.whole);
```

or with a getter but that also gives me an error

Comment: _"with a getter but that also gives me an error"_ What's the error?

Comment: Just a note, if you gave a double like 3.005 and parsed both sides as integers, the leading 0's would be ignored so if you print `whole + "." + fraction` it would give 3.5. This may or may not be a problem depending on what you want to do with that information.

Comment: You can't handle irrational numbers this way.  Does this matter to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class:

```
class WholeAndFraction {
    long whole;    // or String I do not know
    long fraction; // or String I do not know

    // constructor, getters
}
```

and pass around an instance of this class.

There is no way to return 2 values from a method. You can return a List or an array with 2 values in it, but it is debatable if it is more elegant or not..

Answer (score 0):

These two lines in your constructor declare **local** variables:

```
int whole=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
int fraction=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
```

These exist only within the constructor itself.

You need to declare `whole` and `fraction` as class members (as shown in another answer).  In the constructor, you would remove the datatypes which indicate a variable declaration:

```
whole=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
fraction=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is assigning to method variables (which disappear after the constructor completes), when the assignments need to be instance variables (which will be available to getter methods).

Try changing:

```
public wholeAndFraction(double db) {
    String st= "" + db;
    st=st.replace(".", "-");
    String[] str=st.split("-");
    int whole=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int fraction=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
}
```

To

```
public class WholeAndFraction {
    private final int whole;
    public int getWhole() { return whole; }

    private final int fraction;
    public int getFraction() { return fraction; }

    public WholeAndFraction(double db){
        String st=""+db;
        st=st.replace(".", "-");
        String[] str=st.split("-");
        this.whole=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        this.fraction=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    }
}
```

I've qualified the instance variables with this in the assignment statements, but that is for clarity.

That is the main first issue.  There are other issues, for example, use of "-" will break if the number is negative.  A "." won't be present if the number is a whole number already.  And, the fractional part, as implemented, doesn't capture all of the details of the decimal part of the value.  Using the code, above, "1.02" and "1.0002" both have the same fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class like below:

```
class WholeAndFraction {
    int whole;
    int fraction;

    // constructor & getters
}
```

Also, on a separate note, the way to extract the whole and decimal part from a double is not elegant and proper what you wrote. It could be rewritten as:

```
public WholeAndFraction extractParts(double db) {
    WholeAndFraction  obj = new WholeAndFraction();
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(db));
    obj.whole = bigDecimal.intValue();
    obj.fraction = Integer.parseInt(bigDecimal.subtract(new BigDecimal(obj.whole)).toPlainString().substring(2));
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip the `st=st.replace(".", "-");` by using `String[] str=st.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems that you may have encounter using an approach like this, but if you absolutely have to do this here's a solution for a few of them, check the comments for more info. If you only need to know if the number was negative you can do something like this, but this depends entirely on your usecase.
Using Integers is also a bad idea because if the double is big enough it wont fit...

```
public class WholeAndFraction {

    // You have to use String because numbers like this exists:
    // 1123.0001020
    // 141.07 <- this would become an octal number
    // 6,9   6,09  <- these would give you the same value with doubles
    private boolean negative;
    private String whole;
    private String fraction;

    public WholeAndFraction(Double number){
        String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
        if (numberAsString.startsWith("-")){
            this.negative = true;
            numberAsString = numberAsString.replaceFirst("-", "");
        }

        // Based on Locale you can have . or , as separator
        String[] splitted = numberAsString.split("[\\.,]");
        this.whole = splitted[0];
        this.fraction = splitted[1];
    }

    // getters, setters, toString etc... or just use Lombok to generate it for you
}
```